# How to do parameter encoding in Alamofire 4?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

having trouble getting my head around parameter encoding in Alamofire 4. Before I would use the `ParameterEncoding` enumeration and do something like this:

```
Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0
```

However this has since been replaced with the `ParameterEncoding` `protocol`:

```
public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]

public protocol ParameterEncoding {
    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest
}
```

How could I intergrate this into my current code? How do I encode my current `mutableURLRequest`?

EDIT:

```
static func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, Any>, data:Data?, contentType: ContentType, parameterName: String) -> (URLRequestConvertible, Data) {

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
        urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        urlRequest.httpMethod = Alamofire.HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
        let boundaryConstant = "multipart-boundary";
        let multipartContentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
        urlRequest.setValue(multipartContentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        // Create upload data to send
        var uploadData = Data()

        if data != nil {
            // Add multipart data
            uploadData.append("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            if contentType == .Image_JPEG {
                uploadData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(parameterName)\"; filename=\"file.jpeg\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                uploadData.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            } else if contentType == .Audio {
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMyyyyddsshhmmA" // superset of OP's format
                let audioFileName = "recording-\(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())).mp4"
                uploadData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(parameterName)\"; filename=\"\(audioFileName)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
                uploadData.append("Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            }
            uploadData.append(data!)
        }

        // Add parameters
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            uploadData.append("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            uploadData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        }
        uploadData.append("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        // return URLRequestConvertible and Data
        return (urlRequest, uploadData)
    }
```

When doing a request:

```
let urlRequest = urlRequestWithComponents(urlString: url, parameters: parameters, data: imageData, contentType: .Image_JPEG, parameterName: "question_img")


    alamoManager.upload(urlRequest.1, with: urlRequest.0).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<CustomResponse>) in

     //Some code
    }
```

Answer (score 39):

You can do a simple `Alamofire` request like this.

```
import Alamofire
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import ObjectMapper

//
//

Alamofire.request("hello.com", method: .post, parameters: ["name": "alvin"], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseObject(completionHandler: { (response : DataResponse<YourModelHere>) in


 })
```

You can see that I have used `JSONEncoding` in this request. You can choose your way of encoding in there from any of these.

In `JSONEncoding`

1. default

   `Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)`
2. prettyPrinted

   `Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding. prettyPrinted)`

And in `URLEncoding`

1. default --

   `Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default)`
2. methodDependent

   `Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .methodDependent))`
3. queryString
4. httpBody

   `Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)`

And create your own `Custom Encoding` like this.

```
public struct MyCusomEncoding: ParameterEncoding {

    public func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {

        var urlRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()

        guard let parameters = parameters else { return urlRequest }

        do {

            let data = //

            // Do your custom stuff here, convert your parameters it into JSON, String, Something else or may be encrypted...

        urlRequest.httpBody = data

        } catch {
            throw AFError.parameterEncodingFailed(reason: .jsonEncodingFailed(error: error))
        }

        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

And you can use `MyCusomEncoding` in your `Alamofire` requests.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. I am still a little confused. I have edited my question to include the `urlRequestWithComponents` method. I use this to construct the `URLRequest` before uploading. Would this even need encoding? If so what type? I also can't see anywhere to include `encoding` in the upload method.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to use `MyCusomEncoding` with `Alamofire` ?

Comment: I would also love to see an example of how to use `MyCusomEncoding`.

Answer (score 4):

Use  Alamofire.URLEncoding()

Code Example:

//finalRequest:URLRequest? = nil

```
    do {
        try   finalRequest =  Alamofire.URLEncoding().encode(urlRequest as! URLRequestConvertible, with: parameters)
    } catch {
        //Handle error
    }
    return finalRequest!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
do { 
    let alamofireRequest = try Alamofire.URLEncoding().encode(urlRequest as URLRequestConvertible, with: parameters)
    Alamofire.request(alamofireRequest).response { (dataResponse) in 

    }
} catch {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. please provide more information with your code.